# Tomcat context.xml War Application

Tags: java, tomcat, url, tomcat7, war

Good morning in my timezone.

I changed the web application name in the context.xml.
Before the change the URL was:

```
http//:hostname:port/index.jsp
```

After :

```
http//:hostname:port/newName/index.jsp
```

Problem:
Before the context.xml change, we had in jsp pages the following statement.

```
<script  src="folder1/folder2/js/util.js"></script>
```

Now after the context.xml change we had to update the src attribute to

```
<script  src="newName/folder1/folder2/js/util.js"></script>
```

One of the solutions :
In the folder structure in the web application we made the following change :
Before the change :

```
webapp       
  -META-INF       
  -WEB-INF       
  -folder1
      -folder2

  ....
```

Now we had to copy the folder1 to the newName folder

```
  webapp
      -META-INF
      -WEB-INF
      -newName
         -folder1
            -folder2
```

My question :
 I think this solution is error-prone because we can forget to update to the new 
  location one of the URL in the hundreds of files the application have.
Is there any better solution ? Some kind of redirection we can make inside web.xml ?

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Comment: So your not just changing the name but also moving resources around? I didn't think changing the context name be a problem if all paths are reletive? Moving resources inside the webapp is different. You could write a servlet which handle the path change but I am not sure if you want to go down this path.

Comment: I think you should change the paths in corresponding files and rebuild your application.

Comment: @MinhKieu thanks for the answer, i had edit the question, i just move the resources because i had add the newName to the context , so the src script attribute will look for that name in the URL

Comment: @SangamBelose that was the solution we made and after we change the paths in the files we had to create the newName folder and put the folder1 and subdirectories inside of it. But is there something that we could do to avoid this solution ?

Comment: we use absolute path in our application and keep the path till resources in the properties file. we keep web resources and scripts on web server.if this was the case then it would have been easy to change the path in properties file.

Comment: @tt0686 - you should never use absolute-path to avoid issue like this. As mentioned, if you web application sits behind Apache, you could use Mod rewrite to manipulate the URLs.

Comment: @MinhKieu like you see in the  src attribute i am not using an absolute path, the src= "folder1/folder2..." is relative to the Application context, but when we change the context.xml to add the newName name to the url , before we type http//hostname:port/index.jsp now we type http:hostname:port/newName/index.jsp and by default the browser when requestinf the scripts add the "newName" to URL of the scripts, so before the change the call to the utils.js was http:hostname:port/folder1/folder2/js/utils.js and now is http:hostname:port/newName/folder1/folder2/js/utils.js

Comment: @tt0686 - yes from the browser point-of-view your seeing the full URL however the application should handle the context change without a problem if everything is relative path.